# Better, stronger typed way of getting at controls in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following function:

```
public void rpSearchResults_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord rd = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;

        Literal litCompanyName = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCompanyName");
        Literal litCompanyLocation = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCompanyLocation");
        Literal litCompanyActivity = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCompanyActivity");
        HiddenField hdnUserID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnUserID");
        HyperLink lnkEmail = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkEmail");
        HyperLink lnkMicrosite = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkMicrosite");
        Literal litRecommends = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litRecommends");

        litCompanyName.Text = rd["CompanyName"].ToString();

        // Construct location info
        litCompanyLocation.Text = "";
        string[] addressParts = {"City","Region","Postcode"};
        bool prior = false;
        foreach (String part in addressParts){
            if (prior) litCompanyLocation.Text = litCompanyLocation.Text + ", ";

            string addressBit = rd[part].ToString();
            if (addressBit == null || addressBit.Trim() == "") prior = false;
            else
            {
                litCompanyLocation.Text = litCompanyLocation.Text + rd[part].ToString();
                prior = true;
            }
        }

        // ... and so on, mapping stuff from the database to fields.
    }
}
```

It is fired by an event on my Repeater, and is used to populate a list of search results. All the various controls being found are present in the Item Template for the repeater.

This all works, but I hate having to do it like this. I hate having to search for a control by string, and I hate having to do casts to get the controls into a state I can manipulate. If anything goes wrong - for instance, if I make a typo - the error is only picked up at runtime, and it can often be quite difficult to track down, as these functions seem to fail silently, rather than creating a big noticeable error page.

This code is written now, and it works. But in the future I'd like to write it in a different way that is strongly typed, so that any errors will make themselves known at compile time. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: MVC3 (Razor) solves this with strong typing and Dynamic. But you seem to be caught in WebForms, not much luck there.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it this way and not just use the binding available in the markup instead of having literal controls littered everywhere? EX: `Company Name: <%#Eval("CompanyName")%>`...

Comment: @Quintin Robinson Yeah, because of the `litCompanyLocation` field in the search results. The database has entries for town, country, zip code etc, with none of those being required fields, so I needed to work a bit to get the output looking right. Putting it in an event like this also gives me more control in other areas.

Comment: @Oliver I can understand the standpoint of control, but you can do the same logical formatting in the view (markup) of the databound control and still use the fields if you like without problem. This is one of the primary goals/uses of databound controls and it seems that you are doing twice the work that should be needed to accomplish the task. Note I am not trying to be critical here I am just offering a suggestion for a more terse & flexible solution.

Comment: @Quintin Robinson Thanks for the advice. I suppose it is personal preference for me. I like having only html on my pages, and all the logic in the code behind, even if it takes a bit more work. I find that that way, it's easier to find where everything is when I need to change things later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your controls into a strongly-typed custom control (including ASCX user controls) and only have to use `FindControl()` once:

```
CustomControl myControl= (CustomControl) e.Item.FindControl("oMyControl");

myControl.litCompanyName.Text = rd["CompanyName"].ToString();
```

Comment: That's a pretty nice idea. I do like having an excuse to make custom controls, I think they make everything much neater. It is still kind of verbose though, it's a shame there isn't a better way to do it with web forms.

Comment: If you're going to create a custom control anyway, you can just forego using a Repeater and create a SearchResults control—no control IDs in strings and no casting.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Based just on what you posted in your example, you're duplicating the existing data-binding function of the Repeater class using the <%# %> syntax. I haven't used ASP.NET data binding in a long, long time, so on the assumption that you actually have a good reason to do things the long way, here's an answer to your actual question:

Unfortunately, there isn't any easy and strongly-typed way to accomplish what you want, at least not within the "old" (non-MVC -- does that have a name?) ASP.NET framework. The Repeater control holds a Control collection, which only knows that every object inside of it derives from `System.Web.UI.Control`. To be any more specific requires typecasts at run time that could fail if your code and ItemTemplate are not in sync.

There are options to make the problem less painful, each of which has its trade-offs:

1. Leave it the way it is. Your code works, you already know the pain points, and you already know how to avoid them. One of the first rules of practical software development is to never break working code.
2. Wrap all of the controls in your ItemTemplate into something that is strongly typed, such as a ASP.NET user control. This comes pretty close to accomplishing what you want: you only have one opportunity to mess up the `FindControl` or typecast, and once that's taken care of you have typed properties. The downside is the additional work involved in binding your data source to the properties of the controls on your ASCX. If the item template changes only infrequently, this is probably your best option.
3. You can get better run-time error detection by checking if your typecasts actually worked. Using, for example:

   ```
   Literal litCompanyName = e.Item.FindControl("litCompanyName") as Literal;
   if ( listCompanyName == null )
       LogSomeError("litCompanyName", "Literal");
   ```

   The downside, obviously, is that it's more code to type and maintain, but if you really are finding that your runtime errors are being swallowed silently, this may end up saving you time in the long run. Plus, it will let you more gracefully recover from a bad typecast 
   without forcing the entire method to bail due to an exception.
4. Avoid using the ASP.NET Repeater (or any other ItemTemplate-based control). This is more of a suggestion for future products, since my first suggestion would be similar to @Henk's comment -- use MVC. The benefits of the MVC Framework are many, with strongly-typed model binding being one of them. What it doesn't have is the library of existing controls that ASP.NET has -- you would need to make your own repeater-like control using, for example, partial views. It's more work but **a lot** easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - point one is a hard one to follow! The previous people who were working on this project made some really weird, unmaintainable design choices, and it's difficult to resist the temptation to rip half of it out and put in something better.

Comment: Well, the rarely-spoke counterpart to "don't break working code" is that "just because it does its job doesn't mean its not broken." Code that is an maintenance nightmare of bad design choices and spaghetti code is, by at least some metrics, "broken". It then becomes a choice of resources: will you save enough maintenance costs later to justify the time spent doing a re-design, re-implementation, and re-test? Questions like that are why I'm glad I have a program manager to answer them for me.

Comment: +1 for argument 3. Do always you the as operator when using FindControl.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This is the way you need to do it. You are at least casting to the right type in the definition so you have a typed object to work with.

The problem is that the only way of accessing hte controls is using the FindControl approach. This is where the core of the problem is - it would be much better if this could be replaced by a type-defined find.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way around. Max you can do is create enum or constants to pass in findcontrol. Casting you have to do, that's bit annoying with container controls.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this in code...  It's fine, but you're having to type the field names twice (once to create the control, and once to assign a value to it), which increases your chance for typos.

You could just do the assignment in the mark-up of the repeater.  E.g.:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("title")%></td>
...
```

It's still has a runtime vulnerability, but at least you only have to type the field name once that way.

**EDIT --** Per your comment about combining the 3 fields...  It's also an option to do that work in the stored procedure...

```
SELECT
    CAST(address as varchar(100)) +
        CASE WHEN NOT NULLIF(address,'') is null THEN ', ' ELSE '' END +
        CAST (region as varchar(100)) +
        CASE WHEN NOT NULLIF(region,'') is null THEN ', ' ELSE '' END +
        CAST (postcode as varchar(100) as CompanyLocation,
   ...
FROM
    ...
```

Comment: I had it set up like that before, but I ran into some trouble when I wanted to do some logic on the stuff coming out of the database before I put it into the fields. I've included a bit more of the function in my question now.

Comment: That makes sense.  If the mark-up approach appeals to you, you could always do the text formatting in the stored procedure (see my edited answer above) instead of the code-behind.  Not necessarily a better approach...just another option...depends on the circumstances.